# Date intersection and space availability

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, sqlalchemy, availability

I am currently trying to check availability on a "space" within a date range, while this date range can be indefinitely long.
The tables are as follows:

Space:

```
id  available_spaces    name
1   20                  Space 1
2   40                  Space 2
3   10                  Space 3
```

Booking (end_date can be null, this meaning endless booking):

```
id  space_id    start_date  end_date    spaces
1   1           13/12-2017  null        9
1   1           13/12-2017  13/12-2018  10
```

Then i would like to be able to make a search, an example could be:

```
from:   11/12-2016
to:     null (again meaning endless)
spaces: 2
```

This query should return the spaces: Space 2, Space 3, since those both have enough availability for that time interval.

And by changing the amount of spaces needed in the search to 1 instead of 2 should yield the following:
Search:

```
from:   11/12-2016
to:     null (again meaning endless)
spaces: 1
```

Space 1, Space 2, Space 3.
The thing i find hard to solve is the variable amounts of spaces that can be available from month to month, and the ability to have endless bookings.

Comment: Which DB? Interval handling is usually DB specific.

Comment: I am using postgres.

Comment: Read on [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html). They support infinite/unbounded ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Revisited

As always, SQL offers multiple ways to solve a given task. The original proposed solution (below) used a self-join, but another way would be to take advantage of window functions. The idea is to increment the used up space every time a new booking starts, and to decrement when it ends:

```sql
with bs as (
    select space_id as _sid
         , unnest(array[start_date,
                        coalesce(end_date, date 'infinity')]) as _d
         , unnest(array[spaces, -spaces]) as _sp
    from booking
    where end_date is null or end_date >= '2016-12-11'),
cs as (
    select _sid
        -- The inner sum collapses starting and ending bookings on the same
        -- date to a single spaces value, the outer is the running sum. This
        -- avoids the problem where the order of bookings starting or ending
        -- on the same date is unspecified and would produce possibly falsely
        -- high values for spaces, if all starting bookings just so happen to
        -- come first.
         , sum(sum(_sp)) over (partition by _sid
                               order by _d) as _usp
    from bs
    group by _sid, _d)
select *
from space
where not exists (
    select from cs
    where cs._sid = space.id
      and space.available_spaces - cs._usp < 2)
```

The same in Python/SQLAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import array

bs = session.query(
        Booking.space_id,
        func.unnest(array([
            Booking.start_date,
            func.coalesce(Booking.end_date, func.date('infinity'))
        ])).label('date'),
        func.unnest(array([Booking.spaces, -Booking.spaces])).label('spaces')).\
    filter(or_(Booking.end_date == None,
               Booking.end_date >= '2016-12-11')).\
    cte()

cs = session.query(bs.c.space_id,
                   func.sum(func.sum(bs.c.spaces)).over(
                       partition_by=bs.c.space_id,
                       order_by=bs.c.date).label('spaces')).\
    group_by(bs.c.space_id, bs.c.date).\
    cte()

query = session.query(Space).\
    filter(~session.query(cs).
           filter(cs.c.space_id == Space.id,
                  Space.available_spaces - cs.c.spaces < 2).
           exists())
```

---

It is easier to explain the workings of the query using SQL first, and then to build up the SQLAlchemy. I'll assume that a booking and a search will always have a start, or in other words can only be unbounded in the end. Using [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) and [operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html), you should start by finding the bookings that overlap your search.

```sql
select *
from booking
where daterange(start_date, end_date, '[)')
   && daterange('2016-12-11', null, '[)');
```

From found bookings you need to find intersections and sum used space. To find the intersections use the start of a booking and look up bookings that contain it. Repeat for all bookings at hand. For example:

```
|-------| 5
.  .  .
.  |-------------| 2
.  .  .
.  .  |-------------------- 3
.  .  .              .
.  .  .              |---| 1
.  .  .              .
5  7  10             4
```

and in query form:

```sql
with bs as (
    select *
    from booking
    where daterange(start_date, end_date, '[)')
       && daterange('2016-12-11', null, '[)')
)
select distinct
       b1.space_id,
       sum(b2.spaces) as sum
from bs b1
join bs b2
  on b1.start_date <@ daterange(b2.start_date, b2.end_date, '[)')
 and b1.space_id = b2.space_id
group by b1.id, b1.space_id;
```

which given your example data results in

```sql
 space_id | sum 
----------+-----
        1 |  19
(1 row)
```

because there are 2 bookings only and they have the same start date. The query is far from optimal and for each range has to scan through all the ranges, so *O(n^2)* at least. In a procedural setting you'd use an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) or such for lookups and maybe with some suitable indexing and changes could improve the SQL as well.

With the intersecting booking sums you can then check that there doesn't exist a sum that leaves less space than required by the search:

```sql
with bs as (
        select *
        from booking
        where daterange(start_date, end_date, '[)')
           && daterange('2016-12-11', null, '[)')
), cs as (
        select distinct
               b1.space_id,
               sum(b2.spaces) as sum
        from bs b1
        join bs b2
          on b1.start_date <@ daterange(b2.start_date, b2.end_date, '[)')
         and b1.space_id = b2.space_id
        -- Could also use distinct & sum() over (partition by b1.id) instead
        group by b1.id, b1.space_id
)
select *
from space
where not exists(
        select 1
        from cs
        where cs.space_id = space.id
              -- Check if there is not enough space
          and space.available_spaces - cs.sum < 2
);
```

From this it is straightforward to form the SQLAlchemy version:

```
from functools import partial
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import DATERANGE

# Hack. Proper type for passing daterange values is
# psycopg2.extras.DateRange, but that does not have
# the comparator methods.
daterange = partial(func.daterange, type_=DATERANGE)

bs = session.query(Booking).\
    filter(daterange(Booking.start_date, Booking.end_date, '[)').
           overlaps(daterange('2016-12-11', None, '[)'))).\
    cte()

bs1 = bs.alias()
bs2 = bs.alias()

cs = session.query(bs1.c.space_id,
                   func.sum(bs2.c.spaces).label('sum')).\
    distinct().\
    join(bs2, (bs2.c.space_id == bs1.c.space_id) &
              daterange(bs2.c.start_date,
                        bs2.c.end_date).contains(bs1.c.start_date)).\
    group_by(bs1.c.id, bs1.c.space_id).\
    cte()

query = session.query(Space).\
    filter(~session.query(cs).
           filter(cs.c.space_id == Space.id,
                  Space.available_spaces - cs.c.sum < 2).
           exists())
```